# How to order 3 points counter clockwise around normal

Tags: math, graphics, computational-geometry

I have 3 random points and need to order them counter-clockwise in relation to the normal of plane they form (one of them).

So the question is: I have the points, I have the normal - how do I order them counter clockwise?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336682/maintain-a-list-of-points-around-a-center-point-preserving-ccw-order) on using polar form but am unsure if this is what I want and what point should I use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't picked a normal yet, then no matter what order you write three points in, they are ordered counter-clockwise (relative to a suitably chosen normal).

If you already have a normal (let's call it n, and use a, b, c for the points), look at the sign of `n*((b-a)x(c-a))`.  If it is positive, then (a,b,c) is counter-clockwise; if negative, (a,c,b).